# Static data initialised when my program EXITS

Tags: c++, gcc

Sometimes I like to put initialisation code in the constructor of a static object, like this.

```
namespace
{
    struct Init {
        Init ();
    };

    Init :: Init () {
        // whatever
    }

    Init init;
}
```

Yes, I know this is bad in general because you can't rely on the order of initialisations between translation units, but sometimes, for some things, it's okay.

Anyway I don't like the syntax and today I tried out this.

```
namespace
{
    int init = [] () -> int {
        // whatever
        return 0;
    } ();
}
```

When the program ran, the `whatever` code ran **after** `main()`!

I know static initialisations like this happen in an arbitrary order, but I thought the specification required it *all*, in whatever order, to happen *before* `main()` enters.

Is the compiler misbehaving or is there further subtlety?

```
#> gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386 --with-arch-directory=i386 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)
```

Comment: You mean, _after entering_ `main`? Or, really ***after*** main? That would be ... very  very surprising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this in the standard (3.6.2 Initialization of non-local variables [basic.start.init], 4):

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a
>   non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the
>   first statement of main.  If the initialization is deferred to some point in time
>   after the first statement of main, it shall occur before the first odr-use (3.2) of any 
>   function or variable
>   defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.*
>   * A non-local variable with static storage duration having initialization with side-effects must 
>   be initialized even if it is not odr-used (3.2, 3.7.1).)

Seems to say explicitly that in at least some cases, initialization can be deferred until after main enters.

Comment: @Ali: thanks for improving my answer. I won't quibble over the spelling of __initialisation__.

Comment: @david.pfx You are welcome. As for initialization, I believe it should be consistent. If the quoted text uses initialization, then the line below it, IMO, should say it with z as well. But that really isn't the point. The point is: The question and the initial version of the answer was very confusing for me. With the added text from the standard, it is now clear what's going on and what can happen.

Comment: @Ali: Fair enough. The reason I didn't add the extra text first time was that a casual reader will most certainly not understand the terms odr-use, or the other section references, and I saw no point in spending the time to flesh out all the details.

Comment: @Ali: In my dialect of English there are many words (colour, licence, centre, initialise) and units (Celsius, metre, kilo) which I do not adapt to the American usage when contributing to an international site. So I will quote the standard precisely, but use my own spelling and terminology when they are my own words. Some people will be confused, so be it.

Comment: @david.pfx OK, I understand, and let's leave it at that. :)